# Run Visio Macro from Excel and pass parameters

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I wrote the following Excel macro to call another macro in a open Visio file:

```
Private Sub visio_change_shape(Index_value As Integer)

Dim AppVisio As Object
Dim VisioSystems As Object

Set AppVisio = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")
Set VisioSystems = AppVisio.Documents(1)

VisioSystems.ExecuteLine ("Select_Shape_excel")
End Sub
```

This macro works fine. However, when I want to pass an integer through the same macro I get an exception error:

```
Private Sub visio_change_shape(Index_value As Integer)

Dim AppVisio As Object
Dim VisioSystems As Object

Set AppVisio = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")
Set VisioSystems = AppVisio.Documents(1)

VisioSystems.ExecuteLine ("Select_Shape_excel Index_value")  '<--Error occurs here
End Sub
```

Based on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Visio.Document.ExecuteLine) this should be correct. Any ideas why I receive an error?

Comment: Firstly, drop the () around the parameter you're passing to `ExecuteLine` (I know that's what the docs days to do, but it wouldn't be the first time MS docs were wrong).  Secondly you want to pass the value of `Index_value`, so use`VisioSystems.ExecuteLine "Select_Shape_excel " & Index_value`

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks for the feedback, however the the same error still occurs.

Comment: @VBAPete I think you wanted to use `Document` instead of `Documents`. Only the `Document` object has an `ExcecuteLine` Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.document.executeline

Answer (score 0):

To call a procedure you can use:

<procedure name> <arguments>

e.g. beep 17

or

Call <procedure name> (arguments)

e.g. Call beep (17)

A full description can be found at:

[Microsoft VBA - Calling Sub and Function procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)

Comment: Thanks for the link. What would it look like in this example? `Call VisioSystems.SelectLayers.Select_Shape_excel(Index_value)?`

Comment: FYI, SelectLayers is the name of the visio module, where the macro is located.

Comment: As you type text into the editor it should supply you with the various options.

Comment: A few too many options to figure out the right answer...